# While moving partitions, 2gb of unallocated space lost

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, gparted, partition-recovery

While I was moving a partition to the right, I clicked on something and crashed GParted. When GParted started up again, the 2gb of unallocated space was gone, and it said that my harddrive was 2gb smaller than I know it is. How can I recover this space? Is it permanently gone? (BTW, I am running windows XP/ubuntu 12.04 dual boot, and was running GParted off of a Ubuntu 11.10 live USB). I am willing to re-install Ubuntu and/or Windows if need be.

Thanks

Comment: It won't boot, so I have booted off of a live USB, but I gparted still doesn't show the 2gb of space, so i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recover the 2gb by booting off of a live USB stick (ubuntu 11.10) and using gparted to "check" the partition I was moving. The computer still won't boot, but progress has been made.